# Importing FlowTextView into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, github, import, project

I can't figure out how I am supposed to add the project FlowTextView from here:
https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView
Into my Android Elipse Project?`
I can't add it as an Android Library Project.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is structured for use with Android Studio and Gradle for Android. You would need to fork the project and reorganize its code into an Eclipse-compatible project to use it from Eclipse.

Comment: Isn't maven the easier solution? Or how does that work? I've never used android studio nor maven.

Comment: @adrian_rpl: "Isn't maven the easier solution?" -- since the project would not appear to be set up for Maven, no.